# Missing VT-x option in Surface Laptop 3 BIOS

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v

VT-x option is missing Surface Laptop 3 BIOS menu(Intel i7-1065G7 procesor), without this VT-x enabled, I cannot run any virtualization on Windows. Anyone encountered the same problem and know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late on the response so I dont know if you have worked this out already, but it might help someone else. I also have a Surface Laptop 3 but with an AMD CPU etc. Virtualisation was also missing on my BIOS. My issue was that when using Oracle VirtualBox, the 'Start' opting to begin installing Ubuntu was 'grayed out' or unable to be selected. After searching around, all I needed to proceed with installing Ubuntu was to do what [this guide](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-plans-to-add-native-support-for-virtual-machines-in-windows-10/) says.

Essentially I just searched in the Windows taskbar 'Turn Windows features on our off'. Here I was able to enable 'Virtual Machines Platform'. I also enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform although I am not sure if this is necessary. Restarted the system and I was able to proceed and install Ubuntu through VirtualBox! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found a little option using the Oracle Virtual Box for the Intel version of your Surface!

In the *Task Manager*, under *Performance*, you can check that virtualization is disabled. Just follow my easy steps:

1. Run VirtualBox as an administrator
2. Create new virtual machine (it doesn't matter what you choose)
3. Run it for the first time
4. Go to *Machine Settings* > *System* > *Processor*—as you can see, it is set to a default of 1
5. Change the number from one core to more than one and somewhere on the bottom side of the GUI you could see an attention icon that says something like

   > virtualization off. If you save these setting it will be automatically turned on
6. Just press <kbd>OK</kbd> and voila! It will be turned on!

Now when I type this response I checked too if it is enabled in Task Manager and it was, so yeah!